# RSpec and getting puts or logger.info to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, refinerycms

When I'm running my specs like "rspec ." from the command line, I can see puts or logger.info in the console, if i call that code in my spec.  However, if the call to logger.info or puts is in my controller which I'm testing, it doesn't output to the test.log file or the console window.

I'm using RSpec 2 and Rails 3.0.4

Also, this is a refinerycms site, but we have a couple of controllers external to the Refinery CMS we are trying to test.  When I do a puts or logger.info in a normal site, it seems to work fine, even running RSpec.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so we finally figured this out.

The issue is that Refinery requires a default user to be created or it does not let you hit front end pages.  When you first fire it up, it prompts the user to create a default admin login.  So when we were running our tests, our code was never getting hit.  Refinery was redirecting the "browser" during test time to the "create a first user" page.

We created a seed with a default user and then everything worked again.  So the issue was never that doing a "puts" or "logger.info" didn't work in refinery or rspec.  It was that during testing, we never were getting to our controller.